# How to write Travis env variable to file?

Tags: environment-variables, travis-ci

I'm trying to write a custom Travis env variable to a file for a simple proof of concept thing that I need. However, I'm having trouble getting this to work.

How would I define this in the travis yaml file if my variable is called VARIABLE_X ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using linux commands, something like:

`printenv | grep VARIABLE > all_env`

However I don't know how Travis handles the environment (take a look at their docs, [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/)) but it *might* not work as easily due to encryption, but it should work since your apps wouldn't function if they didn't have the same level of access. If such a case occurs, modifying a few parameters (maybe `TRAVIS_SECURE_ENV_VARS`) is worth looking into.

If you solved the problem in another way, consider sharing with the community.

Answer (score 0):

Write the environment variable as usual ([Shell - Write variable contents to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618696/shell-write-variable-contents-to-a-file))

Define the following within `script`:

```
- echo "$VARIABLE_X" > example.txt
```