# Is there a way within bash to replace placeholders in a text file with the contents of variables?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, centos

Is there a way within bash to replace placeholders in a text file with the contents of variables?

For example, I want to send an email notification out that looks like:

```
Dear Foo, 

Alert: <Alert error text 1> 

<Alert error text 2>

blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

I saw a related article ([How to replace ${} placeholders in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415677/344780)) but in the example, it adds static content.  The catch is that "alert error text 1" and "alert error text 2" are always changing.  I'm not aware of a way to use SED/AWK to replace the markers with dynamic content.

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 3):

```sh
e1=dog
e2=bird
sed "
s/<Alert error text 1>/$e1/
s/<Alert error text 2>/$e2/
"
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working - if the alert error text has simple alpha-numeric output, it works fine. But in some-cases, it has additional special characters and when that's present, it appears to be blank in the final output.  Is there a way to help sed cope with variable content that has special characters?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a job for `printf`:

```
template="Dear Foo, 

Alert: %s 

%s

%s"

# Prior to bash 4
instance=$(printf "$template" "$AlertText1" "$AlertText2" "$Body")

# Bash 4+
printf -v instance "$template" "$AlertText1" "$AlertText2" "$Body"
```

Comment: `printf`'s `-v` option appeared in Bash 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -e 's/<Alert error text 1>/'$e1'/' -e 's/<Alert error text 2>/'$e2'/' file.txt
```

where $e1 and $e2 are the variables.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working - if the alert error text has simple alpha-numeric output, it works fine. But in some-cases, it has additional special characters and when that's present, it appears to be blank in the final output.  Is there a way to help sed cope with variable content that has special characters?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the old solution posted here, that can handle command substitution?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030953/1322463

`eval "cat <<EOF
$(<template.txt)
EOF
" 2> /dev/null`

so template could have stuff like:

`Hello $USER, Today is $(date)`

With output of:

`Hello plockc, Today is Sun Jun 26 13:16:28 PDT 2016`

Just make sure you control the template otherwise anything that gets run is run as your user.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
template () {
cat <<!
Dear $1,

I'm fine, hope you are too.

Love $2
!
}

template foo bar
```