# Substitute string with file content in sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm lost trying to do following substitution with sed:

@ edit: to capture the full complexity of my problem,
I added the fact that filenames are contained in variables afterwards.
Solutions might therefore directly use the filenames.

given a variable I='insert.txt':

'insert.txt':

```
Text I wanna skip.

This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines
```

given a variable M='toModify.txt':

'toModify.txt':

```
Insert the new text: here.
```

I would like to replace the 'here' from $M with the content
of $I:

```
Insert the new text: This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines.
```

I tried:

```
sed -e "s/here/$(tail -n2 $I | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' | tr '\n' '\\n')/" $M
```

with error:
sed unterminated `s' command

The problem is that I don't get the spaces and new lines without terminating the s command.

Any solution?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Very similar to [Use the contents of a file to replace a string using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed). There is a fine difference, but that answer may help you.

Comment: In `insert.txt`, how do you differentiate between text to be skipped and text to be inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace one character with two with `tr`. Escaping the individual spaces is pointless anyway. The reason for the immediate error is that you end up escaping the final slash, too:

```
linux$ tail -n2 "$I" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' | tr '\n' '\\n'
This\ is\ text\ to\ insert\ containing\spaces\ and\ new\ lines\/
```

Escaping the spaces is pointless anyway.  I guess you want something like this:

```
linux$ sed '1,2d;$!s/$/\\/' "$I"
This is text to insert containing\
spaces and new lines
```

We delete lines 1 and two; then add a backslash before every newline except the last.

```
linux$ sed -e "s/here/$(sed '1,2d;$!s/$/\\/' "$I")/" "$M"
Insert the new text: This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines.
```

This is one detail of `sed` which isn't entirely portable. But the above works for me on Linux and MacOS. (Note you might need to `set +H` to disable `csh`-style history expansion aka `-bash: !s/$/\\/': event not found` errors).

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! Could you explain what the \ is actually doing? Is it interpreted as a continuation character before the new line?

Comment: Yeah, it escapes the newline so `sed` knows the text continues on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{prs=RS; RS=""; getline s < "insert.txt"; RS=prs}
{gsub(/here/, s)} 1' toModify.txt
```

```
Insert the new text: This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat insert.txt
This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines
> cat toModify.txt
Insert the new text: here
> export I=insert.txt
> export M=toModify.txt
> perl -ne 'BEGIN{$x=qx(cat $ENV{M});$x=~s/here/qx(cat $ENV{I})/e; print $x;exit }'
Insert the new text: This is text to insert containing
spaces and new lines

>
```