# How to replace environment variables into a text file

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have an XML file containing a path which is different depending of my environments. I created a $ENV_PATH variable which contain the correct string. How can I parse and replace `$ENV_PATH` in my XML file by the value of the environment variable?

Comment: using [subst](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/n-subst/) ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? How does the value appear in your XML and how do you want it to appear after replacement? `sed` is a common Unix tool for replacing strings and doing other edits to files. I would recommend that. I'm not sure this is _really_ a GitLab question though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use the contents of a file to replace a string using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running on linux, you can use the `sed` command to do exactly what you're asking. If you have the following XML file in `my_file.xml`:

```xml
<example>
  <my_tag>SUBSTITUTE_ME</my_tag>
</example>
```

You can use the following command:
`sed -i 's/SUBSTITUTE_ME/$ENV_PATH/g' my_file.xml`

This will result in the following file (if ENV_PATH=/dev)

```xml
<example>
  <my_tag>/dev</my_tag>
</example>
```