# Replace string with file content

Tags: sed

```
$ cat input.txt
abc
$ sed -e '/PLACE_HOLDER/ {
    s/PLACE_HOLDER//g
    r input.txt
}' <<< '<div>PLACE_HOLDER</div>'
<div></div>
abc
```

I try to replace PLACE_HOLDER with the content of a file. But it pastes the file content after the matching line. How to just replace the match?

This is not a duplicate of
[Use the contents of a file to replace a string using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790631/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-replace-a-string-using-sed)

- none of the answers there answer my question specifically. For the 2nd one, which use a bash variable. It is not appropriate when the file is very large. For the first one does not have the problem in my example. In fact, my code is exactly the same as the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { old="PLACE_HOLDER" }
    NR==FNR { new=(NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
    s=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' input.txt - <<< '<div>PLACE_HOLDER</div>'
<div>abc</div>
```

The above will work no matter which characters are present in the string you want to match or the file you want to replace it with.

Comment: I don't understand the script but I guess it is a good time to go and read the Awk book 2nd edition.

Comment: @LudovicKuty The Awk book that you should read is Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as it covers basic awk plus GNU awk extensions and the author provides gawk and makes a reference copy available online.

Comment: Didn't know that a 5th edition exists (unpublished through O'Reilly). https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/

Comment: Did you use specific GNU stuff only available in `gawk` and not `awk` ?

Comment: @LudovicKuty no, I said "Using any awk".

Comment: Yes but you specifically advised to read the book Effective AWK Programming, not the book by Kernighan. Thus I thought there was some things specific to `gawk`.

Comment: @LudovicKuty There are some things specific to gawk that are covered by that book, I'm just not using any of them in this answer. gawk is the most widely available awk and has many features n ot available in other awks so if you're going to buy a book about awk IMO it makes sense to get the one that covers what gawk can do in addition to what every other awk can do, hence the recommendation to get edition 5 of this book as it sounded like you were planning to get some other book or get an old edition of this book.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/PLACE_HOLDER/$(cat input.txt)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file
```

Substitute the evaluated expression `cat input.txt` for each match of `PLACE_HOLDER` globally throughout `file`.

Comment: Specifically, the `e` option to run an external command is a GNU extension, and not portable to other `sed` implementations.

Comment: My sed is `$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8`. But I get error `$ sed -i 's/PLACE_HOLDER/cat input.txt/ge' file.txt
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `<div>cat input.txt</div>'`. What is wrong?

Comment: With GNU sed 4.9 I get ```/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'``` and ```/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `<div>cat input.txt</div>'```

Comment: Ooops!. My testing was inadequate. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Like you discovered, the `r` command inserts new lines after the current line.
That's not suitable if you want to embed the contents of another file in the middle of other text on the same line which should not be replaced.

A crude fix is to build a `sed` script from your input file. Notice then that any `&` characters in the input file have to be escaped, as well as any literal newlines.

Because we will be escaping ampersands, I decided to use that as the separator for the `s` command, too.

```
sed 's/\&/\\&/g
     1s/^/s\&PLACE_HOLDER\&/
     $!s/$/\\/
     $s/$/\&/' input.txt |
sed -f - targetfile
```

Unfortunately, because standard input is tied to `-f -` your script can't process standard input for replacements. A simple workaround for that is to save the generated `sed` script to a temporary file and pass that as the value for the `-f` option; this will also be necessary if your `sed` is one which does not accept the script on standard input.

I believe this should be reasonably portable, apart from the notes about `-f -` above.

Demo: https://ideone.com/oVgIni