# Replace a word with multiple lines using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

I'm working on a bash-script that has to prepare an E-Mail for being sent to a user.

It aggregates some data, which ends up being multiple lines of stuff. For the example stored in `$DATA`.

Now, after a bit of stfw I found a few things like `sed -ei "s/_data_/${DATA}/g" mail.tpl` and also [sed replace with variable with multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684487/sed-replace-with-variable-with-multiple-lines). None of them work.

Now the question is, how do I get `sed` to replace something with multiple lines of text?

(Alternatives to `sed` are also welcome!)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai You dont say? :D I even mentioned it in my question...

Comment: As an aside, don't use uppercase for your private shell variables.

Comment: @tripleee why not?

Comment: Because that's how you avoid inadvertent clashes with reserved variables, which are uppercase. There's no consensus on what *exactly* this means but your script's private variables are definitely not "system variables" as intended in this clause in POSIX. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/874188

Comment: @Cobra_Fast any chance you could consider accepting a different answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you build your multiple line text with "`\n`"s, this will work with a simple `sed` command as:

```
DATA=`echo ${DATA} | tr '\n' "\\n"`
#now, DATA="line1\nline2\nline3"
sed "s/_data_/${DATA}/" mail.tpl
```

Comment: I'm getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated 's' command` from that method.

Comment: This is not entirely portable; not all `sed` dialects accept the `\n` digraph to represent a literal newline.  In some other dialects, you will probably need to use a backslash before a literal newline. Other answers on this page show you how to do that in more detail.

Comment: Looking at this again, I don't think there is *any* version of `tr` which can replace one character with two characters; it's simply the wrong tool for this job. The newlines are lost by accident because you incorrectly fail to quote the argument to `echo`, but this has multiple other undesirable side effects; and the `tr` simply does nothing at all here. **This should not be the accepted answer.**

Comment: Yes does not work for me either. Try [this solution (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107459/replace-a-word-with-multiple-lines-using-sed/#22901380)

Comment: Given that the shell is Bash, then there's no need for the (broken) `tr` invocation - [just use `${DATA//$'\n'/\\n}`](/a/39269241/4850040).

Answer (score 32):

You can do this with AWK using variable substitution. We can set a variable in AWK using `-v`, and then use AWK's `gsub` function to substitute all occurrences of a regular expression with that variable.

For example, if the file `test` has the following contents ...

```
foo
bar
blah _data_and_data_
foo
_data_ foobar _data_ again
```

... and the Bash variable `$DATA` is ...

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

... then `awk -v r=$DATA '{gsub(/_data_/,r)}1' test` replaces all occurrences of the regular expression `_data_` in the file `test` with the contents of `$DATA`, resulting in the following:

```
foo
bar
blah 1
2
3
4
5and1
2
3
4
5
foo
1
2
3
4
5 foobar 1
2
3
4
5 again
```

Comment: Oh my god, this WORKS! I wish I could +1 you several more times, you saved me man!

Comment: Hey Kent, this is an old one, but you seem to be missing quotes around $DATA. confirm?

Comment: should add quotes indeed: awk -v r="$DATA" '{gsub(/_data_/,r)}1' test

Comment: Apparently some (?) Awks will dislike this and say `"newline in string"` (though the answer without double quotes around `DATA` will fail in different ways).

Comment: a short explanation for awk-noobs would be nice

Comment: For people confused about the seemingly extraneous `1` after the substitution function, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-an-awk-script).  Short version:  leave the `1` there.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest simply replacing sed with perl command like this:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/_data_/$ENV{"DATA"}/g' mail.tpl
```

Comment: This is the only that worked for me on OSX. All the other sed and awk based approches failed fo me.

Comment: This will fail in unsettling ways if `DATA` contains a slash. But you can `export DATA` and access it from inside Perl as `$ENV{"DATA"}` without getting code and data mixed up. So `'s/_data_/$ENV{"DATA"}/g'` simply.

Comment: @anubhava and @tripleee, you saved my day. This is the only solution that worked for me: neither `sed` nor `awk` could do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

ring bearer's answer didn't work for me; I think the usage of `tr` there is wrong, and the way it's written, it simply strips away newlines by use of `echo`.

Instead, I used `sed`. I used code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) to replace newlines (credit: Zsolt Botykai). I also expected some dollar signs (`$`) in my input so I took care of that too. You might need to add other input handling. Note the use of double quotes in `echo` to preserve newlines.

```
DATA="$(cat whatever)"
ESCAPED_DATA="$(echo "${DATA}" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' | sed 's/\$/\\$/g')"
```

Then you can use `${ESCAPED_DATA}` in `sed`:

```
cat input | sed 's/one liner/'"${ESCAPED_DATA}"'/' > output
```

Just thought I'd share.

Comment: This works well also when multi-line strings have been built in a `bash` script with `$'\n'` construct (the `cat` in the beginning is, of course, then not needed since the string is already in a variable).

Answer (score 13):

I tried it and `sed 's/pattern/\na\nb\nc/g'` but it does not work on all systems. What does work is putting a `\` followed by a newline in the replace pattern, like this:

```
sed 's/pattern/a\
b\
c/g'
```

This appends a line containing `b` and a line containing `c` when the pattern is seen.

To put it in a variable, use double backslashes:

```
export DATA="\\
a\\
b\\
c"
```

and then:

```
sed "s/pattern/${DATA}/g"
```

Note the double quotes.

Answer (score 8):

Echo variable into temporary text file.

Insert text file into mail.tpl and delete *data* from mail.tpl

```
echo ${DATA} > temp.txt    
sed -i -e "/_data_/r temp.txt" -e "//d" mail.tpl
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me after trying many other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Escaping all the newlines with a `\` (except the last one) worked for me.
The last newline must not be escaped not to break the `s` command.

Example :

```
DATA="a
b
c"

ESCAPED=$(echo "${DATA}" | sed '$!s@$@\\@g')
echo "${ESCAPED}" 
a\
b\
c

sed "s/pattern/${ESCAPED}/" file
```

Comment: I had to use double slashes.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [gnu documentation about multiline techniques](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html):

```
sed '/./{H;$!d;}; x; s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/'
```

> The first expression, `/./{H;$!d;}` operates on all non-empty lines, and adds the current line (in the pattern space) to the hold space. On all lines except the last, the pattern space is deleted and the cycle is restarted.
>
> The `x` command fetches the accumulated lines from the hold space back to the pattern space.
>
> The `s///` command then operates on all the text in the paragraph (including the embedded newlines).

Answer (score 2):

You can put your data in a temp file and run:

```
$ sed '/_data_/r DATA_FILE' mail.tpl | sed '/_data_/d'> temp; mv temp mail.tpl
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have tried to put "\n" in the replace part

```
sed 's/[pattern]/\
[line 1]\n\
[line 2]\n\
[line n]\n\
/g' mail.tpl
```

The first line has /\ for readibility reasons. Each line after that is a stand-alone line like you would find in a text editor. Last line is stand-alone, once again for readability reasons. You can make all of this one line if needed. Works on Debian Jessie when I tested it.

Comment: This is so sed.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA=`echo ${DATA} | tr '\n' "\n"`

sed -z "s/_data_/${DATA}/g" -i mail.tpl
```

Try this...