# How to replace word with multiple lines

Tags: macos, sed, awk

I've looked at lots of similar questions and answers but hitting a brick wall.

I have an XML file with a line like this:

```
<blah:formProperty id="_blah" default="%HTML%">
```

I need to replace %HTML% with about 200+ lines like this:

```
&lt;style&gt;
blah
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
blah
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Using sed throws an error because it doesn't like multiple lines.

awk seems like a better choice, but can't figure out how to get it done.

[Replace a word with multiple lines using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107459/replace-a-word-with-multiple-lines-using-sed) is close, but I can't get the awk example to work. How is $DATA defined such that 'echo $DATA' returns multiple lines? Tons of forum topics on this and all say that only

```
echo "$DATA"
```

will print multiple lines.

So this is really a 2 part question. How do I solve my problem above? And how did they get that awk example to work?

Comment: If DATA has multiple lines in it, then `echo "$DATA"` will print multiple lines!  Try `DATA="$(printf "multi\nline\ndata\n")"`

Comment: Which platform are you on? Not all `awk`s are created equal.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. The link I gave above has echo $DATA and then shows multiple line output--never been able to recreate that.

Comment: @PaulEricson Probably its a typo because when you print the string without quotes, newlines are converted to spaces.

Answer (score 3):

> How is $DATA defined such that 'echo $DATA' returns multiple lines?

Quote your multiple lines of text. For example:

```
$ DATA='&lt;style&gt;
blah
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
blah
&lt;/script&gt;'
```

Now if you `echo` the variable, you’ll get

```
$ echo "$DATA"
&lt;style&gt;
blah
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
blah
&lt;/script&gt;
```

> awk seems like a better choice, but can't figure out how to get it done.

Now that you have a variable defined, you can use that variable in `awk` by doing:

```
awk -v var="$DATA" '{sub(/%HTML%/,var)}1' file.xml
```

```
$ cat file.xml 
h:formProperty id="_blah" default="%HTML%">
```

```
$ awk -v var="$DATA" '{sub(/%HTML%/,var)}1' file.xml 
h:formProperty id="_blah" default="%HTML%lt;style%HTML%gt;
blah
%HTML%lt;/style%HTML%gt;
%HTML%lt;script%HTML%gt;
blah
%HTML%lt;/script%HTML%gt;">
```

Now you must be wondering why do you get `%HTML%` in the replacement. This is because there is a special character `&` which tells `sub` function to generate the matched text which in our case is `%HTML%`. To avoid this you need to escape it. Using `\\` will allow `sub` to put a literal `&`. Using `\&` is treated as plain `&` which you don’t want either.

```
$ DATA='\\&lt;style\\&gt;
blah
\\&lt;/style\\&gt;
\\&lt;script\\&gt;
blah
\\&lt;/script\\&gt;'
```

```
$ awk -v var="$DATA" '{sub(/%HTML%/,var)}1' file.xml 
h:formProperty id="_blah" default="&lt;style&gt;
blah
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
blah
&lt;/script&gt;”>
```

#### Update:

As OP stated he is using an `awk` on OSX which doesn’t accept variables with embedded newlines, updating the answer as suggested by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) in comments.

```
awk -v var="${DATA//$'\n'/\\n}" '{sub(/%HTML%/,var)}1' file.xml
```

Comment: You wrapped the var in dbl quotes for your echo. That's not what the example I gave does. I asked how to get echo to display a multi-line var without double quotes.

Comment: I get this error with the \\&s and the awk:

awk: newline in string \\&lt;style\\&gt;
#p... at source line 1.

This is basically the same error I was getting with sed too.

Comment: @PaulEricson: Using unquoted variable references by definition replaces newlines with spaces (word splitting). Your problem is that OSX `awk` (unlike `gawk`, which @jaypalsingh assumes) doesn't accept variables with embedded newlines. You can work around that with passing `-v var="${DATA//$'\n'/\\n}"` to `awk` - you still need to escape the `&` chars as described in this answer, though.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the workaround. I probably should have mentioned the answer used `gawk`.

Comment: so the previous error was with the data only having \&. When I change the data to have \\&. I get this error:

awk: newline in string \\\&lt;style\\\&gt;
... at source line 1

Comment: @PaulEricson Define the `awk` variable like `-v var="${DATA//$'\n'/\\n}”`

Comment: jaypalsingh: You're welcome - now that we know it's about OSX, perhaps you could update your answer with the workaround; @PaulEricson: glad to hear it.

Comment: Got solution working under MacOS. Trying to get it working under linux and getting awk limit error:

    awk: program limit exceeded: replacement pieces size=255



So I think I need a non-awk solution as even if recompiling awk could fix the problem, I can't expect any one else adopting my solution to have to build a custom awk binary.

Perhaps a little more background. I'm working in Eclipse. This awk substitution is running in a custom Builder shell script. Perhaps there is a better way to sub a large text block for a single word?

Comment: The problem is with awk's "var". I changed the line to:

    `awk '{sub(/%HTML%/,"$html")}1' file.xml`

And the error went away.