# using sed with variable containing url

Tags: linux, bash, sed, escaping, debian

80I am trying to read a file and replace a placeholder with the content of another file. The problem is the  variable contains urls which seems to cause problems in sed. In addition: what to do to keep the new lines from images.txt? Is there a way to make my solution work or is there maybe another solution that is better suited for my problem? I want to overwrite content of a file with the content of a backup file. In addition the step should include replacing a placeholder with the content of a third file. Thank you.
What I currently use:

```
<images.html
TEXT=$(<images.txt)
sed 's~URLS~$TEXT~g' imagesbu.html > images.html
```

This does not work and just shows:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 80: unknown option to `s'
```

Content of the file is:

```
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/tuts/165_Shiny_Dice/27.jpg
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/tuts/165_Shiny_Dice/27.jpg
```

IF there is no newline in the file it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace a word with multiple lines using sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107459/replace-a-word-with-multiple-lines-using-sed)

Comment: Refer to the linked question for an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try altering your `sed` delimiter so that it is not a forward slash:

```
sed "s~URLS~$TEXT~g" imagesbu.html > images.html
```

Edit: Your original sed command doesn't work because of the above, and because you are trying to replace a single word with multiple lines. Try `awk` instead:

```
awk -v u="$TEXT" '{gsub(/URLS/,u)}1' imagesbu.html > images.html
```

Comment: Same error but a char 91. I guess I need to escape all special characters in $TEXT. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @user2196234 This is because you were using `/` as delimiter, while it is also in the `$TEXT`. Look for another one that is not in the variable, as it looks like `~` is also in  the var.

Comment: The sed command is failing because of the newlines contained in images.txt - are you trying to replace the placeholder with everything inside the file?

Comment: Yes I do. I would also like to keep the newlines to use them as delimiters later (if possible).

Comment: Is the placeholder on its own line within `imagesbu.html`, or is it contained within some other text?

Comment: It is contained in other text. ...="URLS";