# Using multiline variable in sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have a multiline variable that I captured from STDOUT.
I want to insert an echo command using this multiline variable to line 15 in another script (target).

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST=`cat foo`

echo "$TEST"

sed -i "15i echo \"$TEST\" > someotherfile" target
```

Contents of foo  :

```
apples
oranges
bananas
carrots
```

I thought the sed command read in line feeds, which I confirmed my foo has:

```
user@test$ cat foo | tr -cd '\n' | wc -c
4
```

When I run my test.sh script, I see what's in `$TEST`, but am getting an error for the sed command:

```
user@test$ ./test.sh
apples
oranges
bananas
carrots
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown command: `o'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add complete sample input/output? `TEST` has multiple line string value and you are adding some string before and after... so it is little unclear for me... to insert just content from a file, use the `r` command... `sed '14r foo' target` --> inserts contents of file foo from 15th line onwards to input file target

Answer (score 4):

<sup>*GNU* `sed` is assumed, as implied by the syntax used in the question.</sup>

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read contents of file 'foo' into shell variable $test.
test=$(<foo)

# \-escape the newlines in $test for use in Sed.
testEscapedForSed=${test//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}

sed -i "15i echo \"$testEscapedForSed\" > someotherfile" target
```

- Your problem was that **passing *multi-line* strings to `sed` functions such as `i` (insert) requires the newlines embedded in those strings to be `\`-escaped**, so that `sed` knows where the string ends and additional commands, if any, start.

  - A (nonstandard) [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is used to replace all newlines in `$test` with themselves prefixed by `\`, using [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) `$'\n'` to generate actual newline chars.
- Also note:

  - I've renamed `TEST` to `test`, because [all-uppercase shell-variable names should be avoided](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).
  - I've used modern command-substitution syntax `$(..)` in lieu of legacy syntax `` `...` ``.
  - `$(<foo)` is a slightly more efficient - although nonstandard - way of reading the content of a file at once.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**Solution1:**

```
awk 'NR==15{print;system("cat foo");next} 1' Input_file
```

No need to get the complete file into a variable, we could simply print it whichever line of Input_file you want to print it.

**Solution2:**

```
line=15; sed -e "${line}r foo" target
```

Or (in script mode)

```
cat script.ksh
line=15;
sed -e "${line}r foo" target
```

Where you could change the number of line where you want to insert the lines from another file.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` command in `sed` inserts the lines of text that end with a newline, up until a line that doesn't end with a backslash.  The `a` and `c` commands are similar. Classic `sed` doesn't like the first line to appear on the same line as the `i` command; GNU `sed` isn't as fussy.

If you were writing the command manually, you'd need to write:

```
15i\
echo "apples\
oranges\
bananas\
carrots" > someotherfile
```

At issue now is "how do you want to create this given the file `foo` contains the list of names?".  Sometimes, using `sed` to generate the `sed` script is useful.  However, it can also be intricate if you need to get backslashes at the ends of lines which are subject to an `i` (or `a` or `c`) command, and it is simpler to circumvent the problem.

```
{
    echo "15i\\"
    sed -e '1s/^/echo "/' -e 's/$/\\/' -e '$s/\\$/" > someotherfile/' foo
} | sed -f /dev/stdin target
```

GNU `sed` can read its script from standard input using `-f -`; BSD (macOS) `sed` doesn't like that, but you can use `-f /dev/stdin` instead (which also works with GNU `sed`), at least on systems where there is a `/dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue.
As already mentioned the whole story for sed to be able to insert multiline text in another file is that this new multiline text must have actually literral `\n` for line breaks.

So we can use sed to convert real new line chars to literal `\n`:

```
$ a=$(tr '\n' '\\' <file3 |sed 's#[\]$##' |sed "s#[\]#\0n#g")
#Alternative: a=$(sed "s#[\]#\0n#g" <(sed 's#[\]$##' <(tr '\n' '\\' <file3)))
$ echo "$a"
apples\noranges\nbananas\ncarrots
```

How this translation works:
* First we replace all new lines with a single backslash using `tr`
* Then we remove the backslash from the end of the string
* Then we replace all other backslashes with backaslash and n char.

Since now variable `$a` contains literal `\n` between lines, sed will translate them back to actuall new lines:

```
$ cat file4
Line1
line2
line3
$ sed "2i $a" file4
Line1
apples
oranges
bananas
carrots
line2
line3
```

Result:
Mutliline replacement can be done with two commands:

```
$ a=$(tr '\n' '\\' <file3 |sed 's#[\]$##' |sed "s#[\]#\0n#g")
$ sed "2i $a" file4
```

sed `2i` means insert a text before line2. `2a` can be used in order to insert something after line2.

Remark:
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107459/replace-a-word-with-multiple-lines-using-sed) which seems to be a duplicate, translation of new lines to literal \n seems that can be done with just :

```
a=$(echo ${a} | tr '\n' "\\n")
```

But this method never worked in my system.

Remark2:
The sed operation `sed "2i $a"` = insert variable $a before line 2 , can be also expressed as `sed "1 s/.*/\0\n$a/"` = replace all chars of first line with the same chars `\0` plus a new line `\n` plus the contents of variable `$a` => insert $a after line1 = insert $a before line2.