# Sed - replacing a string with a variable full of weird characters

Tags: bash, variables, unix, sed, escaping

I'm using sed to replace a character in a file with a variable. This variable is basically reading the contents of a file or a webpage which contains multiple hash-like strings like below, which are randomly generated:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'CVo|BO;Qt1B|+GE}+h2/yU7h=5`/wRV{>%h.b_;s%S8-p|>qpf]|/Vf@`&[g~*:&');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '{G2-<^jWRd7]2,?]6hhM^*asg.2C.+k=gf33-m+ZK_{Mt|q*<ELF4|gPjyxtTh!)');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'jSNo9Z;5d]tzZoh-QQ`{M-&~y??$R({:*m`0={67=+mF?L.e+R{;)+4}qCAAHz=C');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '19Vt4=%8j/Z-&~ni0S<]9)J^~sy9dh|h9M_RX2#K0]F9+.v+[BP1d&B&}-FTKIJ,');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'jr7f?T|@Cbo]XVAo}N^ilkvD>dC-rr]5{al64|?_Hz }JG$yEi:_aU )Olp YAD+');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'hm#Z%O!X_mr?lM|>>~r-?F%wi R($}|9R[):4^NTsj+gS[qnv}7|+0<9e-$DJjju');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'tyPHBOCkXZh_4H;G|^.&|^#JPB/f;{}y_Orj!6AH?@wovx+KKtTZ A[HMS9SZJ|N');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'Eb-/t 5D-vPV9I--8F<[^lcherGv.g+|7p6;+xP|5g6P}tup1K.vuHAQ=uWZ#}H^');
```

The variable is defined like so:

```
KEY=$(cat keyfile)
```

I used the following sed syntax:

```
sed -i "s/stringtoreplace/$KEY/" /path/to/file
```

I've also tried different variations, using single-quotes, quotes around the variables

```
sed -i "s/stringtoreplace/"$KEY"/" /path/to/file

sed -i "s/stringtoreplace/"${KEY}"/" /path/to/file

sed -i "s/stringtoreplace/'$KEY'/" /path/to/file
```

I think I "brute-forced" every way possible to put quotes and I don't know how to escape randomly generated characters like those. I keep getting the following error:

> unterminated `s` command

Any suggestions on how to replace the string with the weird-hash-like variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape a string for sed search pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed replace with variable with multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684487/sed-replace-with-variable-with-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else you should use awk:

```
awk -v key="$KEY" '{sub(/stringtoreplace/,key)}1' file
```

That will work no matter what characters "$KEY" contains, except for "&".

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use bash instead of `sed`. That makes the substitution easy, but you'll have to emulate the `-i` option.

Something like this:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
KEY=$(cat keyfile)
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
  echo "${LINE//stringtoreplace/$KEY}"
done </path/to/file >$TMPFILE
mv $TMPFILE /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
KEY=$(cat keyfile | sed -e 's/[]\/()$*.^|[]/\\&/g')
sed -i "s/stringtoreplace/$KEY/" /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the $KEY variable contains slashes, which are the delimiters for your `s` command.

sed can do more than search and replace:

```
sed '/stringtoreplace/{
     d
     r keyfile
}' /path/to/file
```

I'm assuming "stringtoreplace" occurs by itself on a line.

Comment: OP - if the slashes are the problem, then you can use a different delimiter for sed. sed uses whichever character follows the initial 's' as the delimiter - people just use the / as a standard. Is there a special character that is guaranteed NOT to show up in your hashes? If so you could use (for example, a colon) 's:stringtoreplace:${KEY}:'

Comment: @Kevin, if the data is random as indicated in the question, you'll never know what delimiters are safe.

Comment: I recommend that approach only if the OP can determine the function that generates the strings, and whether there are any printable characters that cannot be created by that function. That direction may be more work than it is worth.