# find/replace with sed yields unexpected results

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I'm attempting to find/replace a string found in a number of files spread throughout a directory tree.

I thought I'd use sed for this task.

```
find /some/dir -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/cybernetnews/cybernet/g" {} \;
```

This works as expected with the sample string "cybernetnews", but things get weird when I try to find/replace against this string:

```
preg_match($_SESSION['infos']['num'], $numeric_variable)
```

Where I want to replace the string `$_SESSION['infos']['num']` with the constant `INFOS_NUM`.

So I thought this would work:

```
find /some/dir -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/$_SESSION['infos']['num']/INFOS_NUM/g" {} \;
```

No luck, here is what shows in the test php file after running the above command:

```
preg_match($_SESSION['INFOS_NUMfoINFOS_NUM][INFOS_NUMum'], 
           $INFOS_NUMmeric_variable)
```

I tried escaping the single quote but get the exact same result.  If I escape the bracket, no changes are made.

What character(s) is `sed` getting hung up on, and how do I properly escape it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - replacing a string with a variable full of weird characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535046/sed-replacing-a-string-with-a-variable-full-of-weird-characters)

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$`, `[`, `]` are regex special characters , you must need to escape that in the regex in-order to match those characters literally. To do a case-insensitive match, you need to add `i` modifier at the last.

```
find /some/dir -name \*.php -exec sed -i "s/\$_SESSION\['infos'\]\['num'\]/INFOS_NUM/g" {} \;
```

Comment: To add to this, `$` is a special character as well. It's escaped correctly in the snippet, it just wasn't mentioned.