# sed command throwing error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ubuntu-16.04

I have a simple Bash shell Script to loop through each file in a directory and check is the copyright message is at the top of the file. 
If it's not there is should add it.

The script is giving an error when I try to use a variable in the sed command. I have looked at other similar questions and tried double quotes "", I have tried using a different operator but still can't find the solution. Can someone possibly point out what I am doing wrong?

```
Msg='/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*******************************************************************************
* Copyright message here
*******************************************************************************
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/'

for file in * 
  do
    if grep -Fxq "$Msg" $file
      then
        echo Marvel Message already exist: $file
    else
      if test -f "$file" 
        then
         echo "Adding Message to file: $file"
         sed -i "1s/^/${Msg}\n/" $file
      fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: You need to use delimiters that aren't included in the variable, i.e not `/`

Comment: I have tried setting the delimiter to `|` as in `sed -i "1s|^|${Msg}\n|" $file` but still issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed replace with variable with multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684487/sed-replace-with-variable-with-multiple-lines)

Comment: Have a look at [sed replace with variable with multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684487/sed-replace-with-variable-with-multiple-lines). There you see that you should replace your `sed` line with `sed -i "1s/^/${Msg//$'\n'/\\n}\n/" $file`

Comment: No, no, no, no.  Don't use sed at all for this.  Just do: `{ echo "$Msg"; cat "$file"; } > $file.tmp; mv $file.tmp $file`  Add some traps for cleanup if you want, and stop fooling yourself that `sed -i` will magically protect you from accidentally leaving tmp files on your filesystem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell you are correct, I was just trying to point out why the sed line failed. Your answer is the simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use sed for this. I would use ed:

```
ed "$file" <<END
1i
$Msg
.
wq
END
```

Or, using `sponge` from the moreutils package

```
{ echo "$Msg"; cat "$file"; } | sponge "$file"
```

Comment: I ended up using the pipe sponge, but also used @William Pursell approach mentioned above. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it with marge like this, here with `echo "$Msg" > tmp.txt`
 you are creating a file with your `$Msg` as header of the tmp file. And with `cat $file >> tmp.txt` you are merging the file.

```
for file in * 
do
if grep -Fxq "$Msg" "$file"
  then
    echo Marvel Message already exist: "$file"
else
  if test -f "$file" 
    then
     echo "Adding Message to file: $file"
     #sed -i "1s/^/${Msg}\n/" $file
     echo "$Msg" > tmp.txt
     cat "$file" >> tmp.txt
     mv tmp.txt "$file"
   fi
 fi
done
```

Hope this will help you.